# compiling delphi-pi

Tags: delphi, open-source, delphi-2009, jedi

After Downloading the source, tried to compile the code.

The first bump was missing Jedi components, so downloaded jcl-2.2.1.3817-partnerdvd

Next step was installing , which was fine.

Now After Compiling , the error message is :

> [DCC Fatal Error] Utils.pas(4): F2051
>   Unit JclCompilerUtils was compiled
>   with a different version of
>   JclSysUtils.IJclCommandLineTool

tried to download diffrenct versions, however the owner of the code claim it was compiled with 2.2.

Ideas how to resolve this?

edit: i just removed some references to the jedi from the library path, i hope didn't do any damage. still no go.

EDIT 2: downloaded the 0.57 and not the default resulted in:

> [DCC Fatal Error] Utils.pas(4): F1026
>   File not found: 'JclBorlandTools.dcu'

now it seems as a simple version problem with jcl, ill reinstall(again).

Comment: JCL current version is 2.2.1.3970: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jcl/files/JCL%20Releases/

Comment: Did you check for other versions on your computer which appear in the Delphi search / library path?

Comment: Yes, I am the owner and as far as I remember I have compiled it with Delphi 2010, but I am not sure if this is the issue. I will check it ASAP.

Comment: I don't see how people are expected to figure out how to clean up your library path or old artifacts on your computer, or how to upgrade JCL to the latest version.   Maybe this kind of question is not a good fit for stack overflow. However, honesty compels me to point out that I did ask a "won't build" question not too long about with Indy subversion sources.  I hereby pledge not to do it again.

Comment: i do not expect people to tell me , "remove jklk and its ok", i expect to learn what to look as i see this error, where to look. such as "tools-> options -> Emnviurment options -> delphi options -> library - win32 -> library path" look there to find a reference to any jcl path.(which i did)

Comment: Is it possible that you might have compiled JCL against a different Delphi version on your machine? And can you please try to compile 0.57 tagged source code using an earlier version of JCL (2.1 for example). I don't have Delphi around so I cannot give you a definite answer till the weekend.

Comment: i just reinstalled the jcl and the jvcl. it works fine with simple exapmles. DOWNLOADED 0.57 AND NEW ERROR.

Comment: i gave up on this. maybe another time , when i'll have the chance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most Delphi error and warning messages are pretty clear, but "Compiled with a different version" errors are one of the few exceptions.  What it really means is:

`Something in Unit JclSysUtils (or one of its dependencies) has changed, and Unit JclCompilerUtils, which has a dependency on JclSysUtils, needs to be recompiled now, but only the DCU for it is available.  Unable to locate the PAS file to recompile it.`

Try making sure that the original source code for all the JCL units is available to the compiler.

Comment: And that you don't have a bunch of old PAS or DCU files with the same names in your library path somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I have checked my settings. I have compiled latest revision of delphipi using JCL 2.2.1.3886.

My library path contains following paths:

```
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Soft Gems\Virtual Treeview\Source
C:\Components\jcl-2.2.1.3886\lib\d14
C:\Components\jcl-2.2.1.3886\source\include
```

Delphipi depends three external libraries which are JCL, dxgettext and Virtual Treeview and links to these libraries are listed in the homepage of the project. I think you should check double check your JCL installation and library paths. Sorry, there is nothing else I can do about this. Good luck.

Comment: which version of treeView did you install?

Comment: 4.8.6. But the recent version should be just fine.